# Carrier concentration in the depletion region of PN Junction graph

Tags: semiconductors

I have just started learning about PN junction with the help of this video

[NPTEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x70X_PvzyDs&list=PLF178600D851B098F&index=20)

At time 10-15 minute from the start ,we get this
[image]

The professor claims that from the linear scale it is clearly seen that concentration drops off to zero and thus it is a depletion region that is no free carriers are present. How are we getting this linear scale plot and how is this concentration dropping to zero but in the log scale it is not?

[image]

This is another picture showing the same thing. But how is concentration dropping to zero in linear scale but not in log scale.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with electrical engineering and is rather just a basic graphing problem.

You use a log scale to show a graph over many decades say 10^{-7} to 10^{2}.

On a linear graph you'd probably be able to get a scale something like 0-100. So anything less than 2 or so will look like 0 on the linear graph.